# Deserialize XML to List<>

Tags: c#, xml, list, linq

Is it possible to convert the following XML to List?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA>
    <SIGNATURES>
        <SIGNATURE>
            <UTILISATEUR>John Doe</UTILISATEUR>
            <ACTEUR>Emetteur</ACTEUR>
            <DATE>20160429</DATE>
        </SIGNATURE>
        <SIGNATURE>
            <UTILISATEUR>Philippe Martin</UTILISATEUR>
            <ACTEUR>Responsable Qualité Projet</ACTEUR>
            <DATE>20160503</DATE>
        </SIGNATURE>
    </SIGNATURES>
</DATA>
```

I am looking for the following result:

[image]

But the XML is an example, I do not know the structure in advance so I can not create a class that would have the same structure ... I'm looking for a generic solution.

Thanks.

edit:

I wanted to describe a simple case that I would have adapted but in fact, currently I do not use this XML format. He is like this:

```
<DATA>
    <ELEMENTS Cle="NAME_1">
        <ELEMENT>
          <ELEMENT Cle="TAG_1" Valeur="John Doe"></ELEMENT>
          <ELEMENT Cle="TAG_2" Valeur="6 rue du Marché"></ELEMENT>
          <ELEMENT Cle="TAG_3" Valeur="Responsable marketing"></ELEMENT>
          <ELEMENT Cle="TAG_N" Valeur="..."></ELEMENT>
        </ELEMENT>
        <ELEMENT>...</ELEMENT>
    </ELEMENTS>
    <ELEMENTS Cle="NAME_N">...</ELEMENTS>
</DATA>
```

it "respects" a format but the content is never the same. And I extract the data into some dictionary:

```
public class Element
{
    public string Valeur { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<Element>>>    taElements  { get; set; }

    public Element()
    {
        taElements  = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<Element>>>();
    }

    public void SetXML(string xml)
    {
        var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        var root = document.Root;

        foreach (var elements in root.Elements("ELEMENTS"))
        {
            var _taElement = new Dictionary<string, List<Element>>();

            foreach (var element in elements.Descendants("ELEMENT"))
            {
                if (element.Attribute("Cle") == null) { continue; }

                if (!_taElement.ContainsKey(element.Attribute("Cle").Value)) { _taElement.Add(element.Attribute("Cle").Value, new List<Element>()); }

                var elem = new Element();

                if (element.Attribute("Valeur") != null) { elem.Valeur = element.Attribute("Valeur").Value; }

                _taElement[element.Attribute("Cle").Value].Add(elem);

                if (!taElements.ContainsKey(elements.Attribute("Cle").Value)) { taElements.Add(elements.Attribute("Cle").Value, new Dictionary<string, List<Element>>()); }

                taElements[elements.Attribute("Cle").Value] = _taElement;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But impossible to do Binding of the dictionary in an ItemsControl (which is my final goal).

Comment: What type would the `List` contain in your generic solution?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview

Comment: @NetMage string only

Comment: Hi, I've removed the redundant tags from your title and also removed the `WPF` tag (you might be using WPF but this question isn't about WPF).

Comment: Question doesn't make sense. To deserlialize something means to take its string/binary representation and make it into an object so you can access its properties. If you don't know the type, you can't really do that-- even if you could compile an object on the fly, it would be useless because none of your other code would know how to use it (the type didn't exist when the code was compiled). If you just want to iterate through the string values in the XML, use [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview).

Comment: Well, you could create your deserialized value with XElement, that can then have children and attributes and a value. It seems the most easy solution. Another option would be to build a tree node itself, which would allow you to have a full generic solution. @JohnWu if he would have bindings, and a predictable tree he could use it afterwards by referring to `NodeValue` or `Children` or `Attributes` or `Tag` etc...

Comment: @Icepickle I do not really understand, do you have an example please?

Comment: @WDKyle To be honest, that would be a huge code dump, I guess i could show the reader itself, and then you can decide on how to do implement it behind the seems

Comment: I don't understand how `List<String>` could be used for your situation?

Comment: @NetMage It's not just a List<string>, there is x string for 1 line

Comment: Okay, asking again. What __type__ would the `List<>` contain?

Comment: @NetMage That's the problem, I do not know! Since we can not create a class dynamically ... I'm a little lost.

Comment: Actually, you can create a class dynamically, it just isn't worth it. However, you can simulate a dynamic class with an `ExpandoObject` or by extending `DynamicObject`, but perhaps `List<Dictionary<string,string>>` is simplest - but what you chose depends on what you intend to do with the result.

Comment: I just saw this tutorial (https://blogs.infinitesquare.com/posts/web/c-expandoobject-and-dynamic-properties) I think that may suit me!
I wish eventually to have a binding to a ListBox, DataGrid. With the current structure of my dictionary "taElements" it is not feasible? Since the "columns" are described in lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `List<Dictionary<string,string>>` that will handle most any XML using LINQ to XML. You can extract the name of the element.

```
var xd = XDocument.Parse(doc);
var elementName = xd.FirstChild().Name.ToString().TrimEnd('S');
var ans = xd.Descendants(elementName).Select(d => d.Descendants().ToDictionary(dd => dd.Name.ToString(), dd => dd.Value)).ToList();
```

If you need to bind the `ans` to a `DataGridView`, then you can use a `DataTable`.

Using an extension method, you can convert the `List<Dictionary>` to a `DataTable`:

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable(this IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, string>> rows) {
    var dt = new DataTable();
    if (rows.Any()) {
        foreach (var kv in rows.First())
            dt.Columns.Add(kv.Key, typeof(String));

        foreach (var r in rows)
            dt.Rows.Add(r.Values.ToArray());
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Now you can create a `DataTable` for a `DataSource`:

```
var dt = ans.ToDataTable();
```

Comment: XML files will always have an "ELEMENTS" tag, then "ELEMENT" nodes and then child nodes whose names I do not know. But even with ToList () it remains a dictionary so not possible to bind to a datagrid?

Comment: @WDKyle I don't remember that being a requirement of your original post, but I added how I would handle it.

Comment: I also modified the code to handle any generic "ELEMENTS"/"ELEMENT" tag.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the *XMLSerializer/Deserialize* for documentation. It will serialize a class out to XML, or read an XML stream into a class. [XML Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/introducing-xml-serialization)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DATA data = new DATA();
        data.SIGNATURES = new List<SIGNATURE>();
        data.SIGNATURES.Add(new SIGNATURE() { ACTEUR = "", DATE= "", UTILISATEUR= "" });
        data.SIGNATURES.Add(new SIGNATURE() { ACTEUR = "", DATE = "", UTILISATEUR = "" });

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DATA));
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"Xml.xml"))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, data);
        }

        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DATA));
        TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"myXml.xml");
        object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
        DATA XmlData = (DATA)obj;
        reader.Close();
    }


  public class SIGNATURE
    {
        public string UTILISATEUR { get; set; }
        public string ACTEUR { get; set; }
        public string DATE { get; set; }
    }

    public class DATA
    {
        public List<SIGNATURE> SIGNATURES { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I do not know the structure of XML in advance. So I can not have a SIGNATURE class.